# Labels (?) in VBA-generated Excel chart. Also sorting/colouring

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am using VBA to populate charts from pivot tables. First (as in first pic), I sort values based on month and category (A, C, U etc). Later (as in second pic), I only want to sort by category.

The problem, and root to a severe headache, is that I want the category names under the staples, like I have the months in the upper pic. For some reason, only the name of the first category (the one with the greatest value) is shown.

I have tried googling but I don't know what the labels (?) are called. I tried something with ApplyDataLabels but it wasn't quite right; it added labels on top of the staples. I want them under the X axis.

On another note, I would like the same category to always have the same colour, even though I sort them differently between charts (first by month and name, later by occurence). Is that even possible? (I intend to sort the first chart categories alphabetically later.)

Many thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the labels try this code:

```
Dim myarray As Variant
myarray = Array("A", "B", "C")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = myarray
```

This sets the Category axis labels to the values in the array. The XValues of a series is what you are looking for. It seems that you have multiple series but I guess the upper code should still work.

As for the second question. I think the colours of the series are set based on the order in which you add the series to the chart. So you can either always add the series to the chart in the same order. Another option would be to have a procedure that loops through all series in the chart and colours them according to the series name. Something along these lines:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
   If (ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Name = "A") Then
      ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply! I actually am setting XValue to the Range I want, but it only returns the first value.

I will try your suggestion to my second problem later, thanks a lot!